# When try to open word/excel 2007, I am always getting Microsoft office enterprise 2007 configuration progress pop up. How to get rid of this

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-word-2007

I have office 2007 and 2013 in my system. I uninstalled 2013. Now When I try to open word or excel 2007 files, I am always getting installer popup. How to get rid of this pop up once for all ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running several versions of Office on the same computer and need to set a registry key. The steps are explained in [this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928091/en-us). The core steps are in the section about "Multiple Versions of Word":

1. Start the registry editor
2. Locate and then click to select the following registry subkey: **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options**
3. After you select the subkey that is specified in step 2, point to
   New on the Edit menu, and then click DWORD Value.
4. Type NoReReg, and then press ENTER.
5. Right-click NoReReg, and then click Modify.
6. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
7. On the File menu, click Exit to close Registry Editor.

Comment: I tried this one, Still the pop-up is coming. Any other alternatives to fix this issue?

Comment: Enter the same registry entry in the path for Word 2013. Exchange the `12.0` with `15.0` to set the 2013 value.